# Javascript returns object in browser but nothing in VSCode

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My code works in the browser by returning an object, however if I run this in VSCode or on in the terminal, I either get no output or a null output with no error. I'm trying to figure out how to get this to work on my machine, not just in the browser.

```js
var residential = "residential";
var commercial = "commercial";
var check = "residential";

var make = function(site_type, value) {
  // Define desired object
  var obj = {
    site_type: site_type,
    check: value
  };
  // Return it
  return obj;
};

if (check == "residential") {
  var value = "residential";
  make(residential, value);
} else if (commercial == "null") {
  var value = "residential";
  make(residential, value);
} else {
  var value = "commercial";
  make(commercial, value);
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by output?  the return value of your make function or what you see in the console?

Comment: how exactly are you executing this code in VSCode/terminal?

Comment: `make(commercial, value);` makes no sense since you do nothing with the returned object form the method.

Comment: Chrome (maybe other browsers) will just log the last thing that it has executed when written in the console, in this case it's your `make` function. What are you expecting elsewhere?

Comment: I realize now I had a fundamental misunderstanding of return. Y'alls comments and the answer below solved it for me. Thanks.

Comment: I am developing this script for a 3rd party product that pulls and uses the outputs of return, and I mixed that up with how standard JS works. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no code that produces any output.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
const data = make(residential, value);
const output = JSON.stringify(data);
process.stdout.write(output);
```